# 'pip' is not recognized on python 2.7.12

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

when I try to install beautiful soup with pip, this always happens

```
C:\Python27>pip install beautifulsoup4
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have tried to uninstall python 2.7.12 but when I try, it says that there is a problem with the windows installer package

EDIT:pip is installed under C:\Python27\Scripts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: In Python 3.6, pip is located in a subdirectory named 'Scripts' below the location of Python.exe. Did you look on your drive to see where pip is actually located?

Comment: If pip is indeed installed, try `python -m pip install beautifulsoup4`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
C:\Python\Scripts\pip install
```

Comment: when i try that this happens C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install -U setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\pip.py", line 194, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "c:\python27\pip.py", line 83, in bootstrap
    from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand
ImportError: No module named

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is in the `Scripts` subdirectory. Try this instead:

```
C:\Python27>cd Scripts
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: i get hit with no module named commands.install and when i try to pip install -U setuptools same thing happens